# Passing Parameter back to Component

Tags: angularjs

I am having the worst time with the following code:

```
angular.
    module('albumCarousel').
    component('albumCarousel', {
        templateUrl: '/album-carousel/album-carousel.template.html',

        controller: function AlbumCarouselController($scope, $http) {
            /* the bane of my existence */
            console.log(this.category); // prints undefined..
        }
    }
)
```

In my html, I have the following:

```
<angular-carousel category="songs"></angular-carousel>
```

Going back to the component, in the controller,

```
this.category comes back as undefined.
```

How do I get it to return "songs"

Comment: Read [AngularJS Developer Guide - Components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bunch of googling, I found the answer: $onInit:

```
this.$onInit=function() {
    console.log(this.category)
}
```

I also had to add a binding:

```
    bindings: {
        category: '@',
    }
```

Thanks for all of your help